# Why does DateTime format return as a non-object on my second date format?

Tags: php, datetime, format

I am getting an error that shows only if this DateTime format function is called a second time.  It works fine on the first one, which is something I am assuming because the error only occurs on the line of the second call.

```
if( ! function_exists('month_dropdown')){
    function month_dropdown($field_name = 'month', $selected = '01', $value_format = 'm', $atts = ''){
        for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
            $numObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!'.$value_format, $i);
            $val = $numObj->format($value_format);
            $nameObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!F', $i);
            $text = $nameObj->format('F');
            $months[$val] = $text;
        }
        return form_dropdown($field_name, $months, $selected, $atts);
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in ...application\frontend\helpers\MY_html_helper.php on line 73
```

Line 73 is where the variable `$text` is defined.

Comment: What does [`DateTime::getLastErrors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php) show?

Comment: You do realise what the `F` format represents, right? *"A textual representation of a month, such as January or Sept"*. You appear to be attempting to use it with an integer

Comment: Yes, because it should convert 1 to January, etc.

Comment: Why did I get a vote down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong formatting character. With month integers, use `n`

> m and n
>
> Numeric representation of a month, with or without leading zeros
>
> Example: 01 through 12 or 1 through 12

For example

```
$nameObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!n', $i);
$text = $nameObj->format('F');
```

Demo here ~ https://eval.in/188555